# Firebase Firestore - Iterate collection with restricted security rules

Tags: security, firebase, angularfire, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore I defined a rule like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, list: if request.data.visibility == "public";
    }
  }
}
```

Then I want to get all public documents, so I subscribe to the collection using AngularFire:

```
this.docs = db.collection('documents', ref => ref.where("visibility", "==", 'public')).snapshotChanges();
```

But this throws:

> Missing or insufficient permissions.

Is this supposed to happen? Is it possible to iterate a collection with restricted documents? I'm not a big fan of subcollections, but is that the only way to achieve this?

Comment: Thx for you answer! I wouldn't change the question to show the right answer. It's confusing. It's better to have the question with the wrong implementation and the answer with the right one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, I was missing the list rule, and I also didn't add the documents collection. The final rule is this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /documents/{document=**} {
      allow read, list: if resource.data.visibility == "public"
    }
  }
}
```